# Constexpr lambda implementation - how does this work?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, constexpr

while doing one task I came up across this tricky implementation that would allow you to make constexpr lambdas (which is not allowed out of the box):

[Crazy constexpr lambdas implementation article](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/09/02/static-lambda/)

It basicly boils down to this implementation:

```
template<class F>
struct wrapper
{
    //static_assert(std::is_empty<F>(), "Lambdas must be empty");
    template<class... Ts>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&... xs) const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const F&>(*this)(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }
};

struct wrapper_factor
{
    template<class F>
    constexpr wrapper<F> operator += (F*)
    {
        return{};
    }
};

struct addr_add
{
    template<class T>
    friend typename std::remove_reference<T>::type* operator+(addr_add, T &&t)
    {
        return &t;
    }
};
#define STATIC_LAMBDA wrapper_factor() += true ? nullptr : addr_add() + []
```

usage

```
const constexpr auto add_one = STATIC_LAMBDA (/*i believe you can pass arguments here but i havent tried*/) -> bool
{
    //do stuff
    return stuff;
};
```

I have got 2 questions:

1. I needed to comment out static_assert due to "std::is_empty<_Ty>': no appropriate default constructor available" even without making any instance of this lambda. Anyone knows why?
2. How does this even work? I followed the flow of all the classes and I understand that

a) this part

```
true ? nullptr : addr_add() + [] your_lambda
```

returns a nullptr of a type we want lambda to be (further refered to as "correct_type" )

b) wrapper_factory takes this nullptr of correct_type, constructs wrapper. This wrapper is default initialized.

c) wrapper in operator() forwards the arguments that he is called with (passed in the /* i believe.../* place) to an object that is "wrapper this pointer casted to correct_type".

Now where is the information what routine to call actually passed? I can only see default created empty wrapper that is reinterpreted to some lambda type and called via ().

Best regards

Marcin K.

Comment: Not really a `constexpr` lambda - can't do `reinterpret_cast` in a constant expression...

Comment: Every lambda has a unique type, and "what routine to call" is embedded in that type. UB galore, of course.

Comment: Btw, you will have real constexpr lambdas in C++17 :)

Comment: @T.C. That was a very short and very explaining answer. Can you also tell me what's "UB galore" ?

Comment: Oh and if you are sure of this answer then this seems like a perfect answer to my question. If you don't mind posting it as answer (maybe a bit longer and some references) that would be a perfect answer to accept. Combined maybe with answer to question 1 that J.H.Bonarius added in comments to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

So consider this code

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class F>
struct wrapper
{
    static_assert(std::is_empty<F>::value, "Lambdas must be empty");
    template<class... Ts>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&... xs) const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<const F&>(*this)(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }
};

struct wrapper_factor
{
    template<class F>
    constexpr wrapper<F> operator += (F*)
    {
        return{};
    }
};

struct addr_add
{
    template<class T>
    friend typename std::remove_reference<T>::type *operator+(addr_add, T &&t)
    {
        return &t;
    }
};

#define STATIC_LAMBDA wrapper_factor() += true ? nullptr : addr_add() + []

const constexpr auto add_one = STATIC_LAMBDA(auto x)
{
    return x + 1;
};

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = add_one(a);

    return 0;
}
```

So in MSVS2015, add_one is reported as a `constexpr wrapper<type> add_one = {}`
But in main, `add_one(a)` is reported as `int wrapper<lambda []auto (auto x)->auto>::operator() <int &>(int &xs) const`
And you can see that the friend function `*operator+` in `addr_add` returns the pointer to the lambda function. And the lambda function definition is implicit. The variadic template in the wrapper struct operator() will mimic the lambda arguments.

Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: p.s. note that I replaced `std::is_empty<F>()` with `std::is_empty<F>::value`. is_empty::operator() is new in C++14, but did not seem to work for me in msvs2015. all the operator() does is return the value... so that's your answer to question 1

Comment: Note that it does not work as constexpr i.e. `int n[add_one(1)] = { 1, 2 };
` will not work.

Comment: thats a good answer to question 1. For question 2, I think T.C. answered me in the comment to my question.